# installing github project as a meteor package

Tags: meteor, github

I forked a meteor package on github at https://github.com/kfirufk/angular2-meteor-accounts-ui

now I want to install it on a meteor project that I have. there are tons of information on the net, some recommend using meteorite, others recommend using mgp... but all the information that i find is for very old version of meteor and nothing actually works!

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

## update

I created `packages` directory inside the root directory and cloned the github package to that directory.

I edited `.meteor/packages` file and added `angular2-meteor-accounts-ui`.

now when i run the meteor application i get the following error:

```
While selecting package versions:
   error: unknown package in top-level dependencies:
   angular2-meteor-accounts-ui
```

`angular2-meteor-accounts-ui` is the name of the package of the github project i cloned (in package.json).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this is the procedure I've done myself, and it works:

1. Stop the app
2. edit the packages file and add the package name of your git fork
3. clone your git fork inside the packages folder of your meteor project. When you start meteor, packages inside that folder take precedence over the Internet, so once it finds the package there, it will not check the one in atmospherejs for download.

**Note:** if you want the package to be part of your project code, just remove .git inside the package clone, and add the whole folder to your app repo.

Comment: hi. thanks for your response. updated main post. still not working

Comment: i need to create a relevant package.js for that package. that allowed me to install it. thanks